# Discord Bot (JS) not recognizing mobile mentions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm having a small issue with a bot I'm building using discord.js.  The code below works fine if the user is on the Desktop version of Discord, but does not work on mobile:

```
if (message.content.includes('<@!700150870041690192>')) {
        var authorId = message.author.id;
        var mentionString = '<@!'+authorId+'>';
        var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Naughty Seat");
        message.member.addRole(role);
        message.channel.send(mentionString+', enjoy your naughty seat.');
```

Basically, if the bot is mentioned, you get put into a role.  I believe it could have something to do with how mobile tagging works, but I'm not sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, user mentions on mobile don't have the exclamation mark before the user id.
You could fix your code by replacing your `if` statement with this one using a regular expression :

```js
if (/<@!700150870041690192>|<@700150870041690192>/.test(message.content)) {
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `message` object has a property `mentions` containing a [MessageMentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) object containing all members and users mentioned in the message. Try using this instead of parsing text manually.

To get a `Collection` of mentioned members:

```
message.mentions.members
```

Also, you are manually constructing mentions in your code. You don't need this, as you can mention a user by concatenating them with a string automatically:

```
message.channel.send("Hello, " + message.author);
```